# Xcodebuild script error: *.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode12, xcframework

I have this error pop-up with the new xcode version ( mine is Version 12.4 (12D4e) ).

So the problem is this, I have added a framework to the Frameworks and Binaries section, and inside xcode everything is great, I can build, test, profile, archive, and run my SDK on iOS and iOS simulator, but when I want to build it with Makefile and xcodebuild, it fails and spits out this error:
`/Users/user/Desktop/sdk-ios/SDK/SDK/Pinning.m:10:9: fatal error: 'TrustKit/TrustKit.h' file not found`

The framework in question is added as a `xcframework`.

below this error, is this:
`CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK-agtufexqywklahgqpkyokhljwrbm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SDK.build/Release-iphonesimulator/SDK\ Framework.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pinning.o /Users/user/Desktop/sdk-ios/SDK/SDK/Pinning.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler`

As I said, inside XCode everything works fine, and the Framework header files are found and linked, and I've tested it, everything works when running.

Any suggestions on what to do or where to look? I've read almost everything and the information is getting scarce.

Regards,
Laurynas.

Answer (score 0):

So I've added to the Header Search Paths the path where frameworks are and made that path recursive and this fixed my issue.